# How to compute for mosfet temperature under load

Tags: mosfet, temperature

I would like to know at what temperature will be my mosfet be sitting at under 100% load. The mosfet is [DMT3006LPS](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2005180933_Diodes-Incorporated-DMT3006LPS-13_C434457.pdf).

So assuming a given load of 5A, and is being driven by its rated Rdson(max) - 6 mOhms the mosfet will be consuming :

P = I^2 * R

P = 5 * 5 * 0.006

P = 0.15

The fet will be consuming 0.15 watts. how do i then use this number to compute for at what temperature the mosfet will be theoretically sitting at?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you are driving the MOSFET in such a way that Vds is 30 mV? If not then you should not use \$P=I^2\times R_{DS}\$. Instead you should use \$P= V_{DS}\times I_{DS}\$.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson but its hard to get the value of Vds since there will be some load before the mosfet , its not really certain how much that load will voltage drop. Im still planning the circuit out so i dont really have something to measure. 30mV would sound about right though.

Comment: Yes, it's hard. But is it harder than replacing burned out MOSFETs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the FET will not be "consuming" any power but will be DISSIPATING 0.15W under these conditions.

Next you need to refer to the THERMAL specs in the datasheet:

[image: Thermal Characteristics]

Much of this depends on your ambient conditions and how you've mounted the device (read the notes!) but assuming you are using the "note 5" conditions it says that:

Thermal Resistance, Junction to Ambient is: 99 C/W

This means the device temperature will rise 99 C above ambient for ever Watt being dissipated.

Since you have 0.15 W that means you get 0.15 * 99 = 14.85 C above the 25 C ambient which gets you to: 39.85 C.

Since the max operating temp is 150C, you are good under these conditions.

Comment: I noticed that there are 2 lines of "Thermal Resistance, Junction to Ambient" specs with different notes, but i guess i should assume the worse hich is 99 C/W. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: That's why it's important to read the notes.  You should be able to extrapolate your application from the data given.